# Extract arrays with string to a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I know that there are some posts at SO with a similar issue, but none of those could really help me solving mine. I do have the following **$test** array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(8) "40265656"
      ["text"]=>
      string(29) "10' - 1st Corner - Terengganu"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(8) "40265715"
      ["text"]=>
      string(25) "18' - 2nd Corner - Pahang"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(8) "40265770"
      ["text"]=>
      string(29) "23' - 3rd Corner - Terengganu"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(8) "40265830"
      ["text"]=>
      string(29) "26' - 4th Corner - Pahang"
    }
  }
}
```

and would like to extract only those arrays containing **Pahang** in the **["text"]** key. First I have [tried](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php)

```
$key = array_search('Pahang', $test);
```

and that gives me `bool(false)`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the code where you have `$test`?

Comment: `array_search` does not search recursively and it does not search substrings within strings. It's not that magical. You will have to write your own function which iterates the array and checks within strings of specific keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this way will be right:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array[0] as $arr) {
    if (strpos($arr['text'], "Pahang") !== false) {
        $result[] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `array_search(...)` searches for a value inside an array, but your array is not flat, it's multidimensional, this means you have one or more arrays inside another array.

In your case, you can use `array_filter(...)` that allows you to filter your array elements in a **callable** function.

So, initially you have to define a function that filters the elements:

```
function getPahang($element) {
    return $element['text'] === 'Pahang'
}
```

This function returns **true** when the element text value is equal to 'Pahang', instead it returns **false**.

Now, you have to call `array_filter`, by passing your array and the callable function:

```
$new_array = array_filter($test[0], 'getPahang');
```

You can try a similar script here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c076222dd6d1c6f2675d0241742e6c11da6eff53

Comment: Instead of checking for identity with `'Pahang'`, OP wanted to get all elements, that *contain* Phang, so `strpos($element['text'], "Pahang")` seems more appropriate for the condition in your filter function.